# What happens when a declarator (my/state) is in a for block?

Tags: scope, raku

The following blocks  run a loop assigning the topic to a variable `$var`:

- The first one the `my $var;` is outside the loop
- The second the `my $var;` is inside the loop
- Lastly the `state $var;` is inside the loop

```
my $limit=10_000_000;
{
    my $var;
    for ^$limit { $var =$_; }
    say now  - ENTER now;
}
{
    for ^$limit { my $var; $var=$_; }
    say now  - ENTER now;
}
{
    for ^$limit { state $var; $var=$_; }
    say now  - ENTER now;
}
```

A sample output durations (seconds) of each block are as follows:

```
0.5938845                                                                                                                                 
1.8251226                                                                                                                                 
2.60700803
```

The docs at https://docs.perl6.org/syntax/state motion `state` variables have the same lexical scoping as `my`. Functionally code block 1 and block 3 would achieve the same persistent storage across multiple calls to the respective loop block.

Why does the `state` ( and the inner `my`) version take so much more time? What else is it doing?

**Edit:**
Similar to @HåkonHægland's comment,if I cut and paste the above code so to run each block three times in total the timing changes significantly for the `my $var` outside the loop(the first case):

```
0.600303                                                                                                                                  
1.7917011                                                                                                                                 
2.6640811                                                                                                                                 

1.67793597                                                                                                                                
1.79197091                                                                                                                                
2.6816156                                                                                                                                 

1.795679                                                                                                                                  
1.81233942                                                                                                                                
2.77486777
```

Comment: No the times are for each block

Comment: I get wildly varying results depending on the ordering of the blocks, see: https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/z@3UkElJzM3s8TW0CDewACMrbmquRSAACRXllhkDeak5RcpxEGUKlSDxRVsVeKtFWrBssWJlQpKhlYKSjoKefnlCgq6Cq5@Ia5BII41Vy3UPFQjYKaDSXSjjEgyqrgksSQVj2nGdDVtUAbb//8A

Comment: Per Håkon, one problem may be not using something like [krun](https://github.com/softdevteam/krun/). Aiui: the first shown block assigns a fresh `Scalar` outside the loop and thus saves the cost of creating a fresh `Scalar` on each run thru the loop that's presumably incurred by the second shown block. And both of those blocks can optimize to just a plain loop whereas the third requires creation of a closure which is more expensive. I'm looking forward to an authoritative answer from a guts dev like timotimo or jnthn...

Comment: @HåkonHægland that is indeed strange difference in timing. I'll add this in the question too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short version: in a world without any runtime optimization (type specialization, JIT, and so forth), the timings would match your expectations. The timings here are influenced by how well the optimizer deals with each example.

First of all, it's interesting to run the code without any kind of runtime optimization. In my (rather slow) VM on the box I'm currently on, sticking `MVM_SPESH_DISABLE=1` into the environment results in these timings:

```
13.92366942
16.235372
14.4329288
```

These make some kind of intuitive sense:

- In the first case, we have a simple lexical variable declared in the outer scope of the block
- In the second case, we have to allocate, and then garbage collect, an extra `Scalar` allocation every time around the loop, which accounts for the extra time
- In the third case, we're using the `state` variable. A `state` variable is stored in the code object of the closure, and then copied into the call frame at entry time. That's cheaper than allocating a new `Scalar` every time, but still a little bit more work than not having to do that operation at all.

Next, let's run 3 programs with the optimizer enabled, each example in its own isolated program.

- The first comes out at `0.86298831`, a factor of *16* faster. Go optimizer! It has inlined the loop body.
- The second comes out at `1.2288566`, a factor of *13* faster. Not too shabby either. It has again inlined the loop body. (This case will also become rather cheaper in the future, once the escape analyzer is smart enough to eliminate the `Scalar` allocation.)
- The third comes out at `2.0695035`, a factor of *7* faster. That's comparatively unimpressive (even if still quite an improvement), and the major reason is that it has not inlined the loop body. Why? Because it doesn't know how to inline code that uses state variables yet. (How to see this: run with `MVM_SPESH_INLINE_LOG=1` in the environment, and among the output is: `Can NOT inline  (1) with bytecode size 78 into  (3): cannot inline code that declares a state variable`.)

In short, the dominating factor here is the inlining of the loop body, and with state variables that is presently not possible.

It's not immediately clear why the optimizer does worse at the case with the outer declaration of `$var` when that isn't the first loop in the program; that feels more like a bug than a reasonable case of "this feature isn't optimized well yet". In its slight defense, it still consistently manages to deliver a big improvement, even when not so big as might be desired!